# Android deployment customization

Tags: android, deployment

Is it possible to do custom step during deployment on Android device? For example, I want to check device configuration to find out if my application can run there. 
Of course, I can do test during run time but check during customization looks like a much better solution

Thank you
Yevgeniy

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you have no way to do anything, including check any information about the device before you application is installed and running.

Comment: That is not too bad for a regular application, but for service, especially service that should start at the boot time...

Comment: You are allowed to have your application start at boot time. And in this instance the user would've had to install but not necessarily run your application before booting. But there was nothing about boot time in your original question =)

Comment: Right, my comment is that Android should do a better job for deployment related issues

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create an application (installer) that will install the application and have the installer run the checks then have it download the application.

Also if its simple stuff like not supporting small screens or old versions of Android the [Android Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) would be something to look into.

Comment: Interesting idea! Are there any examples of installer applications?

Comment: I tried Android manifest. it does not work as i expect. Installation is successful, but i have a run-time error during execution. I can check run-time myself, especially considering that run-time throw generic error that does not provide any reasonable information to the user